# ~90% error rate with Stripe webhooks, unpredictable response. Server issue?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, vps, node.js, caddy

I'm setting up Stripe webhooks for the first time. I've made hundreds of test requests and I've had an error rate of around 90%. It's unpredictable as to why the failures occur.

The failure responses on the Stripe dashboard are either:

```sh
Timed out connecting to remote host
```

or

```sh
Failed to connect to remote host
```

My webhook (I've simplified it for testing). Roughly 10% of the time, I get a 200 response with `{received: true}`:

```js
expressRouter.route('/hooks').post( async (req, res) => {

  const event = req.body;

  console.log("Event:");
  console.log(event);

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
      // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
      // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({received: true});
})
```

I have tried these two ways of defining the hook, and also with and without async:

```js
expressRouter.route('/hooks').post( async (req, res) => {
  ...
})
// and 
app.post("/hooks", async (req, res) => {
  ...
})
```

I've been in contact with Stripe support and have tried all their suggestions.
They left me with the following possibilities:

> It possible there is a slow network involved or some other issue with routing.

> The host provider may need to allow Stripe's delivery IP address, too, FYI
> they may be getting blocked before reaching your server

I have added Stripe's IPs to iptables, eg:

```sh
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 3.18.12.63 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm running my Hostinger VPS server with Caddy on Ubuntu 18.04. Could this be an issue with my server set up? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 100 of test requests? In which time frame? TCP connections have a latency, you need to be aware of that.

Comment: @paladin, I've made 100s of requests over the past 24 hours. I normally send 10 in quick succession. Sometimes 5 could succeed, sometimes 0 succeed. Currently at 84% error rate.

Comment: What does quick mean? If you write a loop, which fires 10 requests without delay, it's no wonder why you are getting such a high error rate.

Comment: I've mostly been manually triggering requests with curl, a few seconds apart, but I've also been triggering them by doing proper test sales through Stripe checkout, and get the same errors. I have also tried this by just sending one request, but get an error rate all the same. So, I don't think that's the issue I have, but could you please explain why sending multiple requests may cause an error?

Comment: In example, you have a client and a server. The server is able to handle 2 client requests per second at the same time, no more. Now you have a client which does 2 requests within 1 second, the server is totally fine with it. Now the same client tries to do 3 requests within 1 second. 2 of 3 requests can be answered in time by the server, the 3th requests times out.

Comment: Same applies to IP packages, there cannot be unlimited IP packages on the line, only 1 (ONE) IP package can be on the line, if another IP packages arrives too, one of those packages "dies", which one is random.

Comment: Ah, understood, thanks for explaining. I think I've just fixed it, after a day+ of trying various things! I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1uExj7mMgM&ab_channel=Twilio, and set up ngrok to forward to localhost:4000. I just send a load of requests and they were all successful. I'm not sure quite how this works / why I needed it, but I'm very happy to have it working. I'll answer the question now as well.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have it working.

I installed ngrok via apt (https://ngrok.com/download)

Then followed this: youtube.com/watch?v=S1uExj7mMgM&ab_channel=Twilio,
and set up ngrok to forward to localhost:4000:

```sh
ngrok http 4000
```

I just send a load of requests and they were all successful. I'm not sure quite how this works / why I needed it, but I'm very happy to have it working. If anyone can explain why it wasn't working without this, please let me know!